# Problem connecting Snowflake to DataFactory

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Upon using the DataFacotry Connector to Snowflake, I consistently get the error message below. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
I am using an Azure-managed Integration Runtime.

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL
> https://xxxxxxx.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=2fb149b1-5f57-47ad-a471-8a8db718336c&request_guid=25dcec4f-f680-4f18-b018-363084843708&databaseName=DEMO_DB&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer
> certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'.
>
> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL
> https://xxxxxxx.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=2fb149b1-5f57-47ad-a471-8a8db718336c&request_guid=25dcec4f-f680-4f18-b018-363084843708&databaseName=DEMO_DB&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer
> certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'.
>
> Activity ID: 376547c0-6604-454d-b881-544cb6e7811a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a good idea, from a security perspective, to leave your account id visible like this.

Anyway, the issue is probably that you have mis-configured your connection as snowflake.com is repeated: ...snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com